# Display Chips and Text in multiple rows with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to display chips and long lines of text wrapped in multiple lines inside of a row.

[This is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBO7m.png)

[I want it like this, except for the label and the aligned on the same line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEUtd.png)

My current code:

```
        return new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Wrap(
              spacing: 8.0,
              runSpacing: 4.0,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Tag(tagLabel: 'Chip1'),
                new Text('This is a very, very long text that should wrap. The second line should be shown below the first chip!'),
                new Chip(label: new Text('Chip2')),
                new Chip(label: new Text('Chip3')),
                new Chip(label: new Text('Chip4')),
                new Chip(label: new Text('Chip5')),
                new Chip(label: new Text('Chip6'))
              ],
            )
          ],
        );
```

Any idea?

Comment: Such complex text layout is not available yet. Only rectangle boxes are available.

Comment: WidgetSpan did the trick for me. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840994/how-to-show-icon-in-text-widget-in-flutter) post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap Tag 1 and text 1 in a Row, and all in a Column. And some ajustment in chip size. For default it expand all line from screen.