# How to show Icon in Text widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to show an icon in text widget. How do I do this ?

The following code only shows the `IconData`

```
Text("Click ${Icons.add} to add");
```

Answer (score 242):

Flutter has `WidgetSpan()` to add a widget inside the `RichText()`.

Example use:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: "Click ",
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 14),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: " to add",
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Above code will produce:

[image]

You can treat the child of `WidgetSpan` like the usual widget.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. I just see the icon without the text. P.S. i added this widget in a Column.

Comment: Specify a default style and give the text a `color`, otherwise it might render and not be visible.

Comment: Would be nice to add `alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,` inside to **WidgetSpan** to centralize vertically.

Answer (score 84):

#### Screenshot:

[image]

---

- ##### Using `Wrap`:

  ```dart
  Wrap(
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text('Click'),
      Icon(Icons.add),
      Text('to add'),
    ],
  )
  ```
- ##### Using `Row`:

  ```dart
  Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Text('Click'),
      Icon(Icons.add),
      Text('to add'),
    ],
  )
  ```
- ##### Using `Text.rich`:

  ```dart
  Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
      children: [
        TextSpan(text: 'Click'),
        WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.add)),
        TextSpan(text: 'to add'),
      ],
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: @genericUser Not really true, how long your text is?

Comment: It's flexible text (it can be one short line, or event a very long text. Very similar to comments on stackOverflow) ;)

Comment: @genericUser Ok, so what's wrong in using `Wrap` then, can you ask a separate question?

Comment: copy this: Wrap(
                    children: [
                      Text("Very long text.......... The icon is not at the center of the text"),
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      Text("Very long text.......... The icon is not at the center of the text"),
                    ],
                    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                  ),

Comment: Also I have opened another issue (there is a good example). https://stackoverflow.com/q/68851694/12695188

Comment: Thank for the help text rich is working perfectly for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used wrap in a paginated data table and it works really well. Note: My text isn't very long. I'm not sure how it would behave for long text though.

Answer (score 42):

An alternative might be to use emoji.

In Dart, strings supports escape sequences for special characters. For unicode emoji, you can use \u and curly braces with emoji hex code inside. Like this:

```
Text('Click \u{2795} to add')
```

The result is:

[image]

You can find a complete unicode emoji list here: http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt

Answer (score 23):

Row Widget can be one solution for this issue, but you have to use different widgets to make it happen.

Follow below example.

```
Row(
   children: <Widget>[
     Text("Hi"),
     Icon(Icons.add),
     Text("Hello")
   ]
 )
```

Comment: This can be valid for this user's specific case as the text is very short. But keep in mind that this won't work properly if you need to place icons inside longer paragraphs.

Comment: i am upvoting the answer. but not accepting it due to issue raised by @GaboBrandX

Comment: Also Icons will not align horizontally with text

Answer (score 15):

Another option is `String.fromCharCode(int charCode)`

This is `icons.dart` created by flutter team and charCodes are can found here.

[image]

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 24.0,
  ),
  text: 'This is alarm icon : ',
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: String.fromCharCode(0xe190), //<-- charCode
        style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons', //<-- fontFamily
        fontSize: 24.0,
        color: Colors.red,
       ),
     )
   ],
  ),
)
```

And result :

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think it's better to use the Row widget. here is an example

```
Row(
  children: [
     Icon(Icons.download_rounded),
     Text(" Download")
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use WidgetSpan() on Text.rich().
Here's [a link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/InlineSpan-class.html) for InlineSpan-class.

Answer (score 1):

For simple icons, You can use a Unicode character as regular text, just copy and paste.

You can search and copy Unicodes from [this site](https://unicode-table.com/en/)

```
Text("Enjoy! ❌✅")
```

This method will work with any Text widget and package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/bytedance/RealRichText) Package to achieve this.

I am not able to find the pub of this package.

Here is the Implementation.

```dart
    RealRichText(
      [
        TextSpan(
          text: "A Text Link",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () {
              debugPrint("Link Clicked.");
            },
        ),
        ImageSpan(
          AssetImage("packages/real_rich_text/images/emoji_9.png"),
          imageWidth: 24,
          imageHeight: 24,
        ),
        ImageSpan(AssetImage("packages/real_rich_text/images/emoji_10.png"),
            imageWidth: 24,
            imageHeight: 24,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10)),
        TextSpan(
          text: "哈哈哈",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 14),
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: "@Somebody",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () {
              debugPrint("Link Clicked");
            },
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: " #RealRichText# ",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 14),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () {
              debugPrint("Link Clicked");
            },
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: "showing a bigger image",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
        ),
        ImageSpan(AssetImage("packages/real_rich_text/images/emoji_10.png"),
            imageWidth: 24,
            imageHeight: 24,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5)),
        TextSpan(
          text: "and seems working perfect……",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

You can also check out below issue for more:

[Flutter Issue #2022](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2022)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
Widget _spanIcon(String text, IconData icon, TextStyle st) {
return Row(
  children: [
    Text(text,style: st,),
    Text(
      String.fromCharCode(icon.codePoint), //<-- charCode from icon data
      style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: icon.fontFamily, //<-- fontFamily from icon data
          fontSize: st.fontSize! + 4.0,//you can increase font size for icon here
          color: st.color,
        ),)
  ],
);}
```

and then use it :

```
_spanIcon('11',Icons.access_alarm, TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Color.fromARGB(113, 0, 0, 0))),
```