# More GestureRecognisers For The TextSpan In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I building an application in Flutter and I am in a situation where I got RichText widget with many TextSpan widgets and I need to have two gesture recognizers, one is on double tap and the other is on long press, so how do I do this if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Each `textSpan` comes with its own `text` and `children` property for which you can use the `recognizer` property and implement different taps as needed. 
Consider below example:

```
Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Center(
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan( //  <-- 1
                                text: 'This is a text from first textspan. ',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                children: <TextSpan>[ //   <-- 2
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text: ' This is a text from second textspan ',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      recognizer: LongPressGestureRecognizer()
                                        ..onLongPress = () {
                                          print('Long pressed');
                                        },
                                      children: <
                                          TextSpan>[ //  <-- 3 (children of 2 textspan
                                        TextSpan(
                                            text: ' This is a another text from second textspan',
                                            recognizer: DoubleTapGestureRecognizer()
                                              ..onDoubleTap = () {
                                                print('double tapped');
                                              }
                                        )
                                      ]
                                  ),
                                ]
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                  )
```

The `children: <TextSpan>[]` commented as `2` has a `text` property and corresponding `recognizer` in which I used `LongPressGestureRecognizer()`.  The same `textSpan` (`2`), has `children` property which again can have a sub text span with a text and corresponding `recognizer` in which I used `DoubleTapGestureRecognizer()`.

So the output will be : You can long press on `This is a text from second textspan` and you can double tap on `This is another text from second textspan`.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just wrap the entire Text Span in the gesture detector widget? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Comment: No, because the children list of the RichText requires widgets of type TextSpan so I can't put a GestureDetector above the TextSpan because then it won't accept it

Comment: Do you want two `recognizers` for each `TextSpan` ?

Comment: @DK15 Yes, that is what I want

Comment: Apparently `WidgetSpan` should help you in this situation. Chek this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56928690/1903781)