# Add image to RichText element

Tags: flutter, dart, richtext

I am trying to achieve following:

[image]

To achieve this I am using RichText. Using this I can add multiple text with different styles. But I am not getting idea how I can add image to this TextSpan. May be there is some other element.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do not need third-party libraries to achieve this. With the latest stable release, Flutter has introduced `WidgetSpan`. This is similar to `TextSpan` but you can use any widget instead of just text. Sample code:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: "Click ",
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 14),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: " to add",
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: A reference to the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840994/how-to-show-icon-in-text-widget-in-flutter