# In flutter how can we make validation error messages look beautiful

Tags: user-interface, flutter, validationerror, error-messaging

[image]I am making an application. The UI of login page i have shared. In this i used validation and due to that it shows validation message in red color below textformfield but it looks very ugly. Is there any way that we make this validation error message looks very good on screen like we do natively using different libraries?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the text field decoration in your form via [InputDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html) widget, like in this example:

Your `TextFormField` widget:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: controller,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Example",
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),  
    ),
  ),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value == '') {
      return "Error";
    }
  },
)
```

In particular you can see this two properties:

- [errorBorder property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/errorBorder.html)
- [errorStyle property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/errorStyle.html)

Comment: Thankyou for your response. It will give color to border of text field and some color to validation error message. Do we have any way that these validation message shown inside some icon and icon will be dispayed as error message

Comment: Mmmm... I think is not possible so fast becouse validator() must return String value. But you can see this post for more information about icon inside text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840994/how-to-show-icon-in-text-widget-in-flutter