# Show tooltip when TextSpan is hovered over

Tags: flutter, tooltip

How do I show a tooltip when a particular `TextSpan` is hovered over? I found [Flutter: How to display Tooltip for TextSpan inside RichText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381528/flutter-how-to-display-tooltip-for-textspan-inside-richtext/60382161#60382161) but that is for when a `TextSpan` is tapped on, not hovered over with the mouse, and it uses a `SnackBar`, whereas I want a tooltip.

Unfortunately I cannot just wrap the `TextSpan` in a `ToolTip` because my use case is in an override of `TextEditingController.buildTextSpan` where I'm returning a `TextSpan(children: childSpans)`, which means I have to use a subclass of `TextSpan`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a direct way to do this.

But here is a possible solution using Hover on the whole `RichText` and then identifying which `TextSpan` is the target, and whether or not it has a tooltip.

[image]

Though, it's not an easy ride. Buckle up!

I tried to keep my application as simple as possible:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'TextSpan Hover Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _textKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: RichTextTooltipDetector(
          textKey: _textKey,
          child: RichText(
            key: _textKey,
            text: TextSpan(
              text: 'Hello ',
              children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'bold',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  semanticsLabel: 'Tooltip: Yeah! It works',
                ),
                TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This `RichTextTooltipDetector` is where I handle the Tooltips as `OverlayEntries`.

My `RichTextTooltipDetector` is just a `MouseRegion` on which I will handle the hover events. This event gives me the local position of the mouse. This position, together with the RichText GlobalKey, is all we need to identify whether we have a tooltip to show or not:

1. From the `RichText` Global Key, I get the `RenderParagraph`
2. From this `RenderParagraph` and the `localPosition`of the `PointerHoverEvent`, I get the `InlineSpan, if any
3. When I defined the `TextSpan`, I highjacked the `semanticsLabel`. This let me know easily if I need to display a Tooltip or not.

The rest is just basic OverlayEntry management:

1. Creating an `OverlayEntry` based on the `BuildContext`, an `offset`, and the Tooltip text
2. Displaying the OverlayEntry with `Overlay.of(context).insert(_tooltipOverlay);`
3. After 1 second, hiding the `OverlayEntry`  with `_tooltipOverlay?.remove();`

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class _RichTextTooltipDetectorState extends State<RichTextTooltipDetector> {
  OverlayEntry _tooltipOverlay;
  Timer _timer;

  RenderParagraph get _renderParagraph =>
      widget.textKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderParagraph;

  InlineSpan _span(PointerHoverEvent event, RenderParagraph paragraph) {
    final textPosition = paragraph.getPositionForOffset(event.localPosition);
    return paragraph.text.getSpanForPosition(textPosition);
  }

  String _tooltipText(PointerHoverEvent event, RenderParagraph paragraph) {
    final span = _span(event, paragraph);
    return span is TextSpan &&
            span.semanticsLabel != null &&
            span.semanticsLabel.startsWith('Tooltip: ')
        ? span.semanticsLabel.split('Tooltip: ')[1]
        : '';
  }

  OverlayEntry _createTooltip(
      BuildContext context, String text, Offset offset) {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        left: offset.dx,
        top: offset.dy,
        child: Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white70,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: 3.0),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(text),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showTooltip() {
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_tooltipOverlay);
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => _hideTooltip());
  }

  void _hideTooltip() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _tooltipOverlay?.remove();
    _tooltipOverlay = null;
    _timer = null;
  }

  void _handleHover(BuildContext context, PointerHoverEvent event) {
    _hideTooltip();
    final paragraph = _renderParagraph;
    if (event is! PointerHoverEvent || paragraph == null) return;
    final tooltipText = _tooltipText(event, paragraph);
    if (tooltipText.isNotEmpty) {
      RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
      var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(event.localPosition);
      _tooltipOverlay = _createTooltip(context, tooltipText, offset);
      _showTooltip();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onHover: (event) => _handleHover(context, event),
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response! However, my specific use case is for showing a tooltip when users hover up different spans of text in a `TextField`. I tried several different ways to adapt your approach for my specific use case, but because I am new to Flutter I was unable to get it to work. How should I adapt your approach for a `TextField`? Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you could update your question with a Minimal Code Sample. It always attracts more targeted answers.