# How to put mouse cursor on hyper text in TextSpan in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using something like this to have links in text inside a paragraph

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'This is a going to be a Text which has '),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'single tap',
        style: style,
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () {
            // single tapped
          },
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Now, it works fine, but I cannot have a hand cursor when rolling over the text?

I was looking on how to do it and found [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58260#issuecomment-636390713)

```
MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
  child: Container(
      height: 30,
      width: 30,
      color: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

but is not possible to wrap one of the TextSpans in a Container and MouseRegion.

Comment: You might want to subscribe to and like this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64769

(Do not comment with "Me too")

Comment: Thank you, I will

Comment: @BenHagen is there a place where I can see the new features added to each release for the web channel? Thank you

Comment: I don't know. I scroll through the git commits from time to time. Big things will be in the  release announcements.

Comment: Apparently `WidgetSpan` should help you in this situation. Chek this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56928690/1903781)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently, this feature has been [**added** to `TextSpan`s](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/77754).

As of Flutter `5647407` on `master` (probably going to be in the `2.1.0` release), the mouse cursor is **clickable** (hand cursor) **by default**. So you do not need to take any action other than upgrading Flutter.

#### Manually specifying

You can manually specify the `mouseCursor` property:

```dart
TextSpan(
  text: 'single tap',
  style: style,
  mouseCursor: MaterialStateMouseCursor.clickable,
  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
    ..onTap = () {
      // single tapped
    },
),
```

Furthermore, there are now `onEnter` and `onExit` callbacks for responding to the mouse entering and leaving the text span.

#### Default `SystemMouseCursors.click`

If you take a [look at the commit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/5647407f078c38d5a1a474d3adcd062ff299e905#diff-f448a03ba39ca8c93d63bd76dc0421c08787b2607caa58bfd8ea9a28d0a30b2aR78), you will notice that the default is now `SystemMouseCursors.click` **when you specify** a `recognizer`.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom `WidgetSpan` like this:

```
class MouseRegionSpan extends WidgetSpan {
  MouseRegionSpan({
    @required MouseCursor mouseCursor,
    @required InlineSpan inlineSpan,
  }) : super(
          child: MouseRegion(
            cursor: mouseCursor,
            child: Text.rich(
              inlineSpan,
            ),
          ),
        );
}
```

and wrap your `TextSpan` with it:

```
MouseRegionSpan(
  mouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
  inlineSpan: TextSpan(
    text: 'single tap',
    style: style,
    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
      ..onTap = () {
        // single tapped
      },
  ),
),
```

Comment: This is great however we loose the text style from the parent

Comment: this helps with the older flutter version (tested in windows)