# How to add iconbutton at the end of the text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I add the iconbutton at the end of the text like this ?

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKHS4.png)

I use Row widget but the iconbutton is not in the right place, it is not at the end of the text

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozNfd.png)

This is my code:

```
Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'All about marketing, lead generation, content marketing and growth hacks',
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info),
            iconSize: 12.0,
            color: Palette.appbar,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: You can use it in Row widget.

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: Please add your code here...

Comment: yes, i added my code to the post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840994/how-to-show-icon-in-text-widget-in-flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) with `TextSpan` and [WidgetSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetSpan-class.html).

`WidgetSpan` allow to add your own widget as a part of text.

like this :

```dart
    RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: _text, style: _style),
          WidgetSpan(
            child:  _child
          )
        ],
      ),
```