# Flutter adding icon right after a long text

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a tapable icon right after a long text. I need to use `Text` widget since I'm using `textDirection` and `maxLines` params.

Any ideas?

The problem:
[image]

What I need to get:
[image]

Comment: Show the code that produces this result so that others can try to help you.

Comment: RichText also has maxLines and textdirection. you can wrap the icon in WidgetSpan

Comment: Sorry didn't know it is supported by RichText. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as Karen said it we need to use RichText.

```
 Text.rich(
        TextSpan(
            text:
                "I want to add a tapable icon right after a long text. I need to use Text widget since I'm using textDirection and maxLines params.",
            children: [
              WidgetSpan(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.error_outline,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

the one way is to get char code of an icon, take a look at this answer for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63479589/10127437

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use a stack, let me show you...

```
Container(//Stack Widget needs space to work so be sure to add a container that gives it
    width: double.infinity, //this makes the container match with the screen width
    height: 200,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(//This widget gives position to your button
            top: 100,//This will create a space on top
            left: 0,//This will create a space on left
            child: Container(//Your Container and text widget here
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100),
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                  "This is my text, my text takes more than one line, I want to present my Icon at the end of this text"
              ),
            )
        ),
        Positioned(
            top: 140,
            left: 150,
            child: IconButton(//Put here your icon widget
              iconSize: 30,
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.arrow_left_circle_fill),
              color: Colors.blue,
            )
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: It won't work if you change the text or fontSize.

Comment: Why not? add a TextStyle widget inside the text widget and make everything from there...

Comment: can add an output image based on this code?

Comment: Just added it to the post, very basic, but shows the idea c:

Comment: My problem with this answer is that is not flexible. I don't know the length of my text, it's a bit like adding an icon at the end of stackOverflow comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `EasyRichText` Widget to do this.

https://medium.com/p/865b8771328d

```
var text = "This is my text, my text takes more than one line, I want to present my Icon at the end of this text";

EasyRichText(
  text,
  patternList: [
    EasyRichTextPattern(
      targetString: text,
      suffixInlineSpan: WidgetSpan(
        child: Icon(Icons.error_outline),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```